# C++ Boost::asio::io_service how can I safe destroy io_service resources when program be finished

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I run aync job thread for async io_service work.

I want to destroy this resources used for async job.

- boost::asio::io_service
- boost::asio::io_service::work
- boost::asio::steady_timer
- boost::thread

I manage the singleton object by shared pointer, below code AsyncTraceProcessor. As you know, shared_ptr automatically call the destructor when use count be 0. I want to destroy all resources safe way at that time.

I wrote code below, but there is SIGSEGV error on JVM. (This program is java native library program)

How can I solve it? In my opinion, already queue but not yet executed works throw cause this error. In this case, how can I treat remain works in safety way?

```
AsyncTraceProcessor::~AsyncTraceProcessor() {
    cout << "AsyncTraceProcessor Desructor In, " << instance.use_count() << endl;
    _once_flag;
    cout <<"++++++++++flag reset success" << endl;
    traceMap.clear();
    cout <<"++++++++++traceMap reset success" << endl;
    timer.cancel();
    cout <<"++++++++++timer reset success" << endl;
    async_work.~work();
    cout <<"++++++++++work reset success" << endl;
    async_service.~io_service();
    cout <<"++++++++++io_service reset success" << endl;
    async_thread.~thread();
    cout <<"++++++++++thread reset success" << endl;
    instance.reset();
    cout <<"++++++++++instance reset success" << endl;
    cout << "AsyncTraceProcessor Desructor Out " << endl;
}
```

Error Log

```
AsyncTraceProcessor Desructor In, 0
Isn't Null
++++++++++flag reset success
++++++++++traceMap reset success
++++++++++timer reset success
++++++++++work reset success
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
++++++++++io_service reset success
++++++++++thread reset success
SIGSEGV
++++++++++instance reset success
AsyncTraceProcessor Desructor Out
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text! Copy-paste the actual text instead. Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why are you triggering the destructor explicitly? (There is only one situation where that makes sense - and this is not it!)

Comment: I edit mark down writing. I don't trigger the destructor explicitly. The AsyncTraceProcessor Object managed by singletone object, but I just define the definition of the destructor. And above error log is printed when the destructor called.

Comment: Using the destructors explicitly leads to undefined behaviour when the language invokes the destructor the second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is unlike Java or C# - basically any garbage collecting language runtime. It has deterministic destruction. Lifetimes of object are very tangible and reliable.

```
async_service.~io_service();
```

This is explicitly invoking a destructor *without deleting the object*, or before the lifetime of the automatic-storage variable ends.

The consequence is that the language will still invoke the destructor when the lifetime does end.

This is not what you want.

If you need to clear the work, make it a `unique_ptr<io_service::work>` so you can `work_p.reset()` instead (which does call its destructor, once).

After that, just wait for the threads to complete `io_service::run()`, meaning you should `thread::join()` them before the thread object gets destructed.

> Member objects of classes have automatic storage duration and will be destructed when leaving the destructor body. They will be destructed in the reverse order in which they are declared.

### Sample

```
struct MyDemo {
    boost::asio::io_service _ios;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> _work_p { new boost::asio::io_service::work(_ios) };

    std::thread _thread { [&ios] { ios.run(); } };

    ~MyDemo() {
         _work_p.reset();
         if (_thread.joinable())
             _thread.join();
     } // members are destructed by the language
};
```

Comment: Added a minimal sample struct that uses the language to do the work, as intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I miss use the destructors explicitly. I use delete to pointer. And io_service.reset() method to release io_service work. But if I try join, the main class is not finished because async work cannot be finished explicitly. I just use io_service.stop() and io_service.reset() sequentially.

Comment: I never suggested io_service::reset anywhere. That was unique_ptr::reset! stop () is simply a bad idea in most cases

Comment: I treated all remained works in service. I use stop and reset after that. In this case, there was not any problem. Tell me more why stop() is bad idea than using unique_ptr::reset() ?